# How to add labels folder to my YOLOv8 Project

Tags: python, yolov8

I am working on a wildfire detector project and ı use Computer vision Engineers train yolov8 tutorial step by step video but ı am runnning an issiue my YOLOv8 cant detect the labels folder

heres the main class

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
reuslts = model.train(data="trainer.yaml", epochs=1)
```

here is my trainer.yaml file

```
path: -CENCORED-/Masaüstü/CustomObjectDetection/data

train: img
val: img

names:
  0: fire
  1: smoke
```

and ı get this error
WARNING ⚠️ no labels found in detect set, can not compute metrics without labels

Comment: It can be helpful if you provide the dataset structure, an example of the image - label pair, and a full start training log before the error.

Answer (score 0):

The one of the working structures for the yolov8 Object Detection dataset is the following:

```
└── dataset
    ├── train
    │   ├── images
    │   │   ├── img_name_1.jpg
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── labels
    │        ├── img_name_1.txt
    │        └── ...
    └── val
        ├── images
        └── labels
```

The train/val paths in the dataset.yaml file will look like this:

```yaml
path: ./dataset

train: train
val: val

names:
  0: fire
  1: smoke
```

The system will look for the **labels** folder in the directories you have provided as train/val arguments in the dataset.yaml file.

Comment: Still not working same issue

```WARNING ⚠️ no labels found in detect set, can not compute metrics without labels```